$set field using another field with rust
how can I set one field using another field from the same document in MongoDb in Rust?
I tried this, but it just sets "$another_price" literally as value
   let update = doc! {
        "$set": doc! {
           "price":  "$another_price"
        }
    };
    coll.update_many(doc! {}, update, None)


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

The link provided by @1sina1 helps. To be more specific, you need to put your update course in an update aggregation pipeline. See this official doc

This doesn't work with Rust driver

The Rust Driver Docs seem to imply that a pipeline is possible.

Finally made it to work thanks to the suggestions in the comments.
What I was missing is to put the $set statement in a vector, which denotes the usage of aggregation pipeline.
let update = vec![doc! {
        "$set": doc! {
           "price":  "$another_price"
        }
    }];
    coll.update_many(doc! {}, update, None)

